# Can't run PIC24EP128MC206 at rated speed

Tags: pic, clock-speed

I got a PIC24EP128MC206 because of its rated speed of 70 MIPS.  (For whatever reason, it is rated in MIPS, while most other PIC24s are rated in MHz.)

Since my understanding is that one instruction on the PIC24 takes one Fcy clock cycle, I am trying to configure the clock so Fcy is as close to 70 MHz as possible.  However it seems I can only run it at about half the rated speed -- around 31.5 MHz.  Anything higher than that, and the PLL stops doing its thing.

I am using the internal FRC clock, since I don't need exact timing anywhere (not using UARTs for example).  The nominal FRC frequency is 7.37 MHz, which can be adjusted from 6.52 MHz to 8.20 MHz using the OSCTUN register.

As a reference, I am using the [PIC24EPXXXGP/MC20X datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70657E.pdf).  Here is the relevant section on setting up the clock:

[image]

and here is my setup code:

```
// configuration fuses for PIC24EP128MC206

_FICD( ICS_PGD1 & JTAGEN_OFF )
_FWDT( FWDTEN_OFF )
_FOSC( POSCMD_NONE & OSCIOFNC_OFF & IOL1WAY_ON & FCKSM_CSECME )
_FOSCSEL( FNOSC_FRC & IESO_ON )
_FGS( GWRP_OFF & GCP_OFF )  

int main(void)
{

    RCONbits.SWDTEN = 0;            // Disable Watch Dog Timer

    // configure Oscillator
    // Fosc= Fin*M/(N1*N2), Fcy=Fosc/2
    // with default 7.37 MHz FRC clk, Fcy = approx 7.37*34/(2*2*2) = 31.3 MHz

    PLLFBD = 32;                   // M=34      (ANYTHING HIGHER DOESN'T WORK)
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 0;         // N1=2
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;        // N2=2

    __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);  // set up to switch to FRC+PLL
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);  // do the switch

    while(OSCCONbits.COSC != 0x00); // wait for switch to take place    
    while(OSCCONbits.LOCK != 1){ };     // wait for PLL lock
```

Fsys = 34*7.37/2 = 125.29 which is near but not below the acceptable range of 120 to 340 MHz.

With the values show above the clock works and I get a nice output of around 31.5 MHz as measured using the CLKO pin (which is the same as Fcy, the instruction cycle clock).  The 31.5 MHz compares well with my calculated value of 31.3 MHz above, given that the 7.37 MHz FRC clock may be off somewhat.

[image]

I would like to use an M value of 76, which would give me an instruction cycle time of 70 MHz.

But if I make the value of M any higher than 34, the PLL becomes unstable and the clock output reverts to around 3.70 MHz, which is half of the FRC frequency (implying the PLL circuit is out of the picture).  When it is running, I can sometimes see some flashes of the higher frequency on the scope, as if the PLL is trying to start up and can't stabilize.  As one can see from my code sample, I am waiting for the PLL lock before continuing.

**UPDATE:** This seems somehow related to the final frequency, not the PLL Fsys frequency. I tried the following combination and it also worked:

```
PLLFBD = 120;                  // M=122     (ANYTHING HIGHER DOESN'T WORK)
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE = 1;         // N1=3
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST = 0;        // N2=4
```

which results in a PLL frequency of 300 MHz a Fcyc of 37.46 MHz (measured, 37.7).

I was a little concerned maybe you couldn't run at 70 MIPS using the internal FRC, but the datasheet for the PIC24E oscillator says "the FRC postscaler output can be used with the internal PLL to boost the system frequency (FOSC) up to 140 MHz for 70 MIPS instruction cycle execution." so I'm not trying to do the impossible.

Another **UPDATE:** I tried a second board and got the same results -- I can't seem to set Fcy to a frequency higher than 40 MHz without the PLL dropping out.  I also tried hooking up a buffered 24 MHz clock into OSC1 and configuring the system to use that as a extral clock (EC) with PLL.  Exactly same results.

How can I get a faster clock to work?

**FINAL UPDATE:** Turns out that the person doing the board layout put a 0.1 uF cap on VCAP without looking at the datasheet and I never caught it either. I swapped that out with a 10 uF 16v low ESR (datasheet called for 4.7 uF or higher) and now I can run at 70 MIPS.  See accepted answer re how I found this was the problem.

Comment: To remove confusion about the PLLDIV/PLLFBD register, the datasheet refers to the value of the 9 bits in the PLLFBD register as PLLDIV, so there is no inconsistency.

Comment: PLLFBD or feedback divider makes logical sense and it appears that the use of the 9th bit = 1 causes it to fail (>32) (assuming 1~32 as valid divide ratios) Sounds like a M counter speed failure. Does it run hot? Is it sensitive to +/-0.1 Vcc variations? When PLL loses sync it should be in Freq mode and when locked in Phase mode so VCO should be stuck at min or max F depending on what mixer puts out to VCO filter. VCO has almost 3:1 max:min tuning range.

Comment: @justing Thanks, your comment made me look at the PLLFBD register again, and I see that the field within it is named PLLDIV, so there is no inconsistency.  I removed that part from my question.

Comment: @tcrosley Are you performing any other tests to determine if the clock is running (and at what speed) other than monitoring the CLKO pin with the scope?  (also, i agree they make no reference in the datasheet as to which clock it should be outputting!)

Comment: @Richman It is failing at 32 or above, which is the 5th bit, not the 9th or highest bit.  The ratios run from 2 to 513.  The chip is not running hot at all.  I have no way of modifying the VCC since it is driven off an internal regulator.  I think I can get a hold of another board though, and will check to see if the problem is the same on it.

Comment: @tcrosley  In the family reference manual it does state it as Fcy as the output clock on OSC2.  (forget about these family sub datasheets!) http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2F70580C.pdf&ei=29XOULj5LYmQiQK8g4HoCA&usg=AFQjCNEtlOonwt6DWsOID8asXn1ntuWXJw&sig2=JDfvD5E1V6BZX47QgqASCw&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.cGE&cad=rja

Comment: @justing I ran some test code that I have running on an 80 MHz PIC32 and it seemed to run about twice as slow, but I haven't done any exact timing tests.  I will check that.

Comment: @justing Thanks for the link to the individual Oscillator datasheet for the PIC24E.  I was a little concerned maybe you couldn't run at 70 MIPS using the internal FRC, but it says "the FRC postscaler output can be used with the internal PLL to boost the system frequency (FOSC) up to 140 MHz for 70 MIPS instruction cycle execution." so I'm not trying to do the impossible.  Interestingly, the power on reset value of PLLDIV is 48 (whereas it is failing for me at around 32 or above).

Comment: Can you try disabling the fail safe clock monitor? (FCKSM_CSECMD). Maybe that keeps switching back to the FRC oscillator for some reason.

Comment: @tcrosley Just for my knowledge, is "one Fcy clock cycle" equal to 4 clock cycles? I'm just asking because I thought it takes PICs ~4 clock cycles to process a instruction. (As compared to a AVR where it takes ~1 cycle to processed an instruction.)

Comment: @Garrett I believe that is true (4 clock cycles per instruction) for the smaller PICs (PIC16 etc.), but for the PIC24, most instructions (except branches) take only one instruction cycle, which is two clock cycles.

Comment: Just on the off chance ... have you checked the power supply voltage is well within spec, or towards the high side? say 3.3-3.4V   If it's marginal, that could explain a lot.

Comment: @justing Disabling the clock monitor had no effect.

Comment: @BrianDrummond VCC is 3.297 volts.

Comment: Then the power's not the problem.  IMO it was worth asking though!

Comment: @tcrosley : As I stated in my answer, while the VCC may be nominally 3.297V, is there a heavy ripple?  Also: how old is this chip? Fresh out of the package? Have you tried a different chip?

Comment: @KitScuzz There is about 20 mv of ripple peak-to-peak on the Vcc line.  The chip is new; the boards were stuffed about two months ago.  I just tried a different board (we just have two working) and got the same results.

Comment: @tcrosley : What's the frequency of the ripple? Did you size the internal Vreg capacitor properly? It sounds like since this is a locking issue and not a setting issue you're having some other problems with the board that aren't related to your code.  You might contact Microchip directly to see if there's some new unpublished errata for the specific chip you're using.

Comment: @KitScuzz -- we have a winner.  Turns out that the person doing the board layout put a 0.1 uF cap on VCAP without looking at the datasheet and I never caught it either.  I swapped that out with a 10 uF 16v low ESR and now I can run at 70 MIPS.  Thank you.  Add your suggestion to your answer below and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out example 7-2 in the pic24E family reference manual (FRM) titled "Code Example for Using PLL with 7.37 MHz Internal FRC":

```
// Select Internal FRC at POR
_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_FRC & IESO_OFF);
// Enable Clock Switching and Configure Primary Oscillator in XT mode
_FOSC(FCKSM_CSECMD & OSCIOFNC_OFF & POSCMD_NONE);

int main()
{
    // Configure PLL prescaler, PLL postscaler, PLL divisor
    PLLFBD=63;            // M=65
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0; // N2=2
    CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=0;  // N1=2

    // Initiate Clock Switch to FRC oscillator with PLL (NOSC=0b001)
    __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0x01);
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);

    // Wait for Clock switch to occur
    while (OSCCONbits.COSC!= 0b001);

    // Wait for PLL to lock
    while (OSCCONbits.LOCK!= 1);
}
```

It looks like the critical step you're missing is **__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01);**

Also, looking at the math: 7.37*(76/(2*2)) == 140.03MHz which is slightly outside the allowed range, assuming that 140MHz is actually the maximum range (don't ask me why but for some reason it seems like it may be 120MHz).

If this still doesn't work then perhaps there's just an issue with your power supply.  The internal FRC oscillator is unstable under temperature and voltage stress, so perhaps you should check to see if you have too much noise.  This would make the FRC wonky as well as the VCO used in the PLL, preventing a lock.

If you look at table 30-18 in the pic24EP128MC206 datasheet, it tells you that over the temperature and voltage range you have about a ±1% for some models and ±2% for others.  Figure 31-9 shows the variation with a stable voltage over a temperature range.  There doesn't appear to be an analysis of voltage variation at a stable temperature.

If you're trying to get a stable run at a high frequency I would just grab a crystal.

---

EDIT (from comment):
So from the sounds of your other posts about your conditions it sounds like you should look elsewhere for a problem. What's the frequency of the ripple? Did you size the internal Vreg capacitor properly? It sounds like since this is a locking issue and not a setting issue you're having some other problems with the board that aren't related to your code.

---

EDIT:

Glad this turned out to be the right answer! Good luck debugging the rest of the board!

Comment: XT mode wont run that fast.

Comment: ...? I mean grab a crystal and run it through the PLL.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I changed my code to use __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x01) but there was no effect.  Also updated my original post.  Thanks.

Comment: It turns out we have a buffered 24 MHz clock being used elsewhere on the board, so I ran a line from that to the OSC1 input and reconfigured things to use that as an external clock (EC) source.  Got exactly the same results -- I can't seem to set an Fcy above 40 MHz.

Comment: The person doing the board layout put a 0.1 uF cap on VCAP without looking at the datasheet (which calls out for a minimum of 4.7 uF) and I never caught it either. I swapped out the 0.1 uF with a 10 uF 16v low ESR and now I can run at 70 MIPS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PICs, and obviously you seem to know what you're doing. But are you sure the `PLLDIV` doesn't exist? Are you sure you have the correct chip or datasheet?

**TABLE A-1 MAJOR SECTION UPDATES states:**

> Updated the All Resets values for CLKDIV and PLLFBD in the System
>   Control  Register Map (see Table 4-35).

So maybe you have an older chip (if this effects anything, I only skimmed the datasheet.)

> There is a minor inconsistency in the documentation; Figure 9-2 and
>   Equation 9-2 refer to a PLLDIV register, which doesn't exist on this
>   microcontroller

If you're sure you have the correct chip and datasheet, that seems like a major discrepancy, enough to almost make me think you may have a counterfeit or defective chip (as long as you do know what you're doing.)

And it looks like you are following this, from the datasheet:

> If the PLL of the target device is enabled and configured for the
>   device start-up oscillator, the maximum oscillator source frequency
>   must be limited to 3 MHz < FIN < 5.5 MHz to comply with device PLL
>   start-up conditions. This means that if the external oscillator
>   frequency is outside this range, the application must start-up in the
>   FRC mode first. The default PLL settings after a POR with an
>   oscillator frequency outside this range will violate the device
>   operating speed. Once the device powers up, the application firmware
>   can initialize the PLL SFRs, CLKDIV and PLLDBF to a suitable value,
>   and then perform a clock switch to the Oscillator + PLL clock source.
>   Note that clock switching must be enabled in the device Configuration
>   Word.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to justing, I discovered that there is no inconsistency after all, the PLLDIV field is simply the only field within the PLLFBD register so I think you can go ahead and delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [PIC24E reference manual, Section 07. Oscillator](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70580C.pdf). It has a more in-depth explanation of the oscillator section and the PLL. Especially, on page 7-26, it has an example of exactly what you want: use the FRC and the PLL (even though it is for 60MHz). THis example sets the configuration bits differently that your example code - esp. it doesn't automatically switch to the user-defined clock source.

I also see that you enable the clock monitor - it might be that it triggers for some reason and then switches back to the normal FRC.

Regarding the PLLDIV: I think this is a misconception. The data sheets always talk about the values used (e.g. PLLDIV), which are part of larger registeres (PLLFBD in this case). The same is for PLLPOST and PLLPRE in the image you posted - they are part of the CLKDIV register.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to justing above, I have disabled the clock monitor but it didn't allow me to run any higher.  I understand now that PLLDIV is the field and PLLFBD is the register.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with dsPICs at 50MIPS using the internal RC oscillator and PLL. Give this a try:

- Set the part to use FRC with divide-by-N and PLL directly (FRCPLL) - I see no reason to start with another clock then switch to it. Also disable any clocks coming outside and any external oscillator sources - set them as GPIO lines if the options exist.
- As the first lines in main(), set PLLFBD, PLLPOST and PLLPRE, then wait for the PLL lock.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the PLL which didn't not lock on the high frequency from my external oscillator. My problem was the [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) of capacitor on the VCAP input. It must be less to 1 ohm (see PIC24E datasheet), and in my case the ESR was 4 ohm, and it was not running.

So thanks for the tip!